# PHP class constructors and methods

Tags: php, class, function, constructor

I just started learning PHP and I am having trouble with its syntax. I am learning how to write a class in php, and I used a syntax kinda similar to Java. However, I can get neither its constructor nor regular method to work and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php 
class bento {
  public $food;
  public $staple = "rice";
  protected $veggie = "kale";

  public function __construct($fd){
    $food = $fd;
  }

  public function getstaple(){
    return $staple;
  }
}

$chicken=new bento("chick");
echo "<br>".$chicken->food;
echo "<br>".$chicken->staple;
$fd=$chicken->getstaple();
echo "<br>".$fd;
echo "<br>".$chicken->getstaple();
?>
```

Here is the result that I have got:

```
//result    

rice


//end of result
```

Basically, out of 4 lines, I only got one line to work (print out the $staple variable). The constructor did not assign "chick" value to $food. The getstaple() function did not return any value.

I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: You need to use $this for instance properties, e.g. $this->food = $fd. Unlike Java you can't just reference the property name directly.

Comment: Will you be selling some [bento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento)? Send some to Spain! (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to a class member, you should use $this->food or $this->staple

```
class bento {
  public $food;
  public $staple = "rice";
  protected $veggie = "kale";

  public function __construct($fd){
    $this->food = $fd;
  }

  public function getstaple(){
    return $this->staple;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, do you know how to implement multiple constructor?

In Java, I can do some thing like:

class bento{

bento(){
this("rice");
}

bento(String fd){
food = fd;
}

Comment: The closest you can get in PHP is a constructor with default values for the parameters: __construct($fd = 'rice')

Answer (score 0):

The same in java, you need to access your class variables using the "this" keyword. In php, you would do something like:

```
$this->methodName();
```

or

```
$this->variableName
```

Comment: Actually in Java you don't need to explicitly reference "this"; that's the difference with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP all variables are local to the scope they are defined within (with a few language provided exceptions like the superglobals $_GET, $_POST, $REQUEST, $_SERVER etc..)

This means that when you reference $food within your method your are referring to $food as it is defined within that method in other words a function variable as opposed to the instance property that you intended.

For instance methods PHP is nice enough to create for you a reference to the instance that a method was called on called `$this` This allows for you to reference properties and methods of an object from within the object itself via this format.

```
$this->food = $fd
```

Another thing to note is class methods and properties are not accessible this way. They require the use of the scope resolution operator `::` so to get at a staticly defined class property or method you would use:

```
ClassName::method();
```

or

```
ClassName::$property;
```

As with `$this` php provides some easy access to the class properties via the `self` and `static` keywords.

`self` is a reference to the class that a static method was defined on.

`static` is a reference to the class that the static method was called on.

To illustrate the difference see this code

```
class A {
     static public $toWho = "Class A";

     static public function sayHelloSelf(){
          echo "Hello ".self::$toWho;
     }

     static public function sayHelloStatic(){
          eecho "Hello ".static::$toWho;
     }
}

class B extends A {
     static public $toWho = "Class B";
}

B::sayHelloSelf(); // echos Hello Class A
B::sayHelloStatic(); // echos Hello Class B
```

Answer (score 0):

this keyword is used to access the class member  within the current class.
You create class you have assign some value for variable $food.
then within the function you have tried to access the variable but $food is class variable we cannot access the class members without object or scope resolution operator. 
"this" has current object name .